# Django: Remove/Change Field Text in HTML Django Forms

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I have a Django form:

```
from django import forms
from hello.models import Whisper

class WhisperForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Whisper
        fields = '__all__'
```

I'm showing it in an HTML page like such:

```
<form action="Whisper" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>
            {{form}}
        <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Whisper">
    </div>
</form>
```

The form shows up correctly, but shows the model name in a rather ugly manner, like:

```
Whisper:[*This is the text field]
```

Is there any way I can remove the Model from sticking to the text field or at least change what it displays?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended method, as described [in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields), is through the `labels` variable in the form's `Meta` class.

```
class WhisperForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Whisper
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {'whisper': 'Custom label text here'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default labels for the form in it's `__init__`, like this:

```
class WhisperForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Whisper
        fields = '__all__' 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WhisperForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['whisper'].label = 'Whisper'
```